# What kind of breakout cables do I need for this rackmount setup?

Tags: cable, rack, rackmount

I am going to be building out a rack and I would like to re-use all the existing hardware for my NAS device and just put it in a rackmount case.

I currently am running FreeNAS inside a Silverstone SFF tower case:
http://www.silverstonetek.com/product.php?pid=452&area=en

With this Mini-ITX mobo:
http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813157467

Using a IBM ServeRaid 1015 HBA card:
[http://www.amazon.com/LSI-SAS9220-8i-PCI-Express-Controller-46C8933/dp/B00DV5AY2U](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00DV5AY2U)

I have 8 WD Red Drives in my storage array.

I want to move it to this rackmount case:
http://www.norcotek.com/product/rpc-2208/

Do I even still need to use my HBA card?  Will a single reverse breakout cable cover all 8 drives or would I need two?  Since this mobo only has 6 SATA connectors, would a 2nd reverse breakout cable even work with only 2 SATA ports left?
http://www.norcotek.com/product/c-sff8087-4s/

Or should I just stick with my HBA card and use 2x 8087 Mini-SAS to Mini-SAS cables?
http://www.norcotek.com/product/c-sff8087-d/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An 8087 cable is 4 "SATA cables" wrapped in to a single bundle. If you use the two reverse breakout cables, then only 6 drives will be connected. You should keep your HBA card and use two 8087 Mini-SAS to Mini-SAS cables.

Comment: ty sir, just wasn't 100% sure :)